# RewriteEngine in apache.conf without .htaccess?

Tags: apache

I want to avoid .htaccess and add stuff to apache2/apache2.conf instead, because I heard .htaccess can slow down Apache.

This Rewrite doesn't work inside apache2/apache2.conf. I tried with  but no luck either.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
  RewriteRule [do things]
</IfModule>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after adding this to apache2.conf? Does it reside inside the correct `VirtualHost`?

Comment: I did restart Apache. About the corret VirtualHost: I added my stuff to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and there is VirtualHost setting.

Comment: /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/conf/vhost.conf looks promissing but no luck either.

Comment: check you have the module and try to set your rule in a Directory section

Comment: DOH! `[do things]` included a relative script path which of course was wrong after moving it from .htaccess